# Security Descriptor Relevant for Unnamed Objects?

Tags: windows, security

When creating an unnamed object, such as with CreateEvent with lpName==nullptr, is the security descriptor passed in LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES relevant for anything? In particular, is the DACL or the integrity level used to restrict access in any scenario?

Comment: security descriptor and name is independent things.

Comment: @RbMm, they're not entirely separate, however. Named objects are mandated to have a security descriptor (i.e. owner, DACL, SACL, control flags) even if the type info doesn't have `SecurityRequired` set (e.g. a named Event object). Unnamed objects only require security if the type sets `SecurityRequired` (e.g. a Process object). If an object requires security, and it isn't explicitly set, then it auto-inherits the container object's inheritable security (e.g. from the BaseNamedObjects directory), if any, or otherwise the default values from the access token.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, agree. for say event, if we not use name for it and not explicit set security descriptor - will be no SD on it. but we can set security descriptor even for unnamed event.  scenario where it used ? formally i view only `DuplicateHandle` when we ask more access than have existing handle. really of course unnamed objects (except processes, threads) can not be opened - so not need sd

Comment: @RbMm, yes, the security descriptor will be checked for most types when duplicating a handle if the caller desires additional access. However, the Object Manager won't check the security descriptor for object types that implement a custom `SecurityProcedure` (i.e. a routine other than the default `SeDefaultObjectMethod`, which is used to set, query, delete, and assign an object's security descriptor). This includes Key (registry), Device, and File objects.

Comment: I don't know why they can't allow this for object types that implement a custom `SecurityProcedure`. I know the WRK (NT 5.2) says there's no means to call it in this case, but it doesn't explain why.

Comment: You guys lost me a bit. I googled SecurityRequired but could not find a good reference. As far as I understand you, an unnamed event and mutex do use their SD for DuplicateHandle? If the requested rights surpass the ones originally specified on CreateEvent/CreateMutex, the token of the caller of DuplicateHandle will be checked against the SD of the object?

Comment: When attached to a process in a kernel debugger, `!handle [handle_value] 2` shows the address of the object's type. Then do `?? ((nt!_object_type *)[address])->TypeInfo` to dump its type initializer, which includes whether `SecurityRequired` is set and whether its `SecurityProcedure` is `nt!SeDefaultObjectMethod`. If security is required, instances always require a security descriptor; otherwise they require one only if named, in order to check access when opened by name. `NtDuplicateObject` also checks security to get increased access, but only if the type uses the default security procedure.

Comment: Note that the Process and Thread types have `SecurityRequired` set. They're opened by numeric identifier rather than by name. `NtOpenProcess` and `NtOpenThread` start by looking up the object address. Then they create an access state and check for SeDebugPrivilege to grant all access to a privileged caller (complicated by protected processes nowadays), and then call `ObOpenObjectByPointer` (or a similar private function in the object manager), which calls `SeAccessCheck` to check the requested access before creating the handle.

Comment: From user mode you can call `NtQueryObject` to get the [`ObjectTypeInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntobapi_8h_source.html) for an object. This includes whether the type has `SecurityRequired`. However, this information is undocumented and subject to change across kernel versions.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you for all the information. Raymond Chen actually addressed my question as well, also listing inheritance and DuplicateHandle as places where the security descriptor is relevant for unnamed objects: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150604-00/?p=45451/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Raymond Chen actually addressed this question in the Old New Thing blog, listing inheritance and DuplicateHandle as places where the security descriptor is relevant for unnamed objects: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150604-00/?p=45451

Comment: Object security is only checked when duplicating a handle to get *increased* access, and even then, this is only possible for object types that use the default security procedure, `SeDefaultObjectMethod`. Because the File and registry Key object types have a custom security procedure, handles for these objects cannot be duplicated with increased access. Also, handle inheritance never requests additional access, so object security is never checked in this case.

Comment: You're also not including Process and Thread objects, which have no name (always since Vista) and are opened by ID. The object security is of course checked in this case, and potentially anywhere else an object is accessed via `ObOpenObjectByPointer` in the kernel.